# Comparing Two Strings And Changing Case of Differing Characters

Tags: r, substring

I'm trying to compare a "master" string to a list of strings using R. Based on this comparison, I'd like all characters in the string which differ from the master string changed to lowercase.

For example: the master string is `"AGG"`. The list of strings being compared to is `["ATT", "AGT"]`. I want to return `["Att","AGt"]`. Order also matters. So `["GGA"]` should return `["gGa"]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn all characters into lowercase first, and turn those characters in the master string back to uppercase.

```
master <- "AGG"
x <- c("ATT", "AGT", "GGA")

chartr(tolower(master), master, tolower(x))
# [1] "Att" "AGt" "GGA"
```

---

**Update:** If you want to compare `x` and `master` character-by-character, try this:

```r
sapply(strsplit(x, ""), \(char) {
  paste(ifelse(char == strsplit(master, "")[[1]], char, tolower(char)), collapse = "")
})

# [1] "Att" "AGt" "gGa"
```

Comment: Thanks! The only issue is that order matters as well. This solution only makes the characters that don't appear in the master lowercase.

Comment: So you want to compare character-by-character by position, and if `x` doesn't match `master`, the character gets made lower case?

Comment: @AnaFsshaie Please check my update. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, exactly @thelatemail